# Importing postman collection in python

Tags: python, json, rest, api, postman

I have received a of postman collection.
It is basically a set of json files describing REST API calling methods in detail.

Now I would like to get rid of postman and use python libraries for these api calls e.g. requests

How to read the structured postman data in an easy way in python?
Any binding available?

Comment: too generic. needs more explanation

Comment: `postman` (or similar [insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/)) should have function "generate python requests" - or at least "generate curl" which you can convert to python on https://curl.trillworks.com/

Comment: postman doc: [Generate code snippets](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/generate-code-snippets/)

Comment: @furas you got me right. could you make it an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`postman` (and similar [insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/)) has function to [generate python requests code](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/generate-code-snippets/) or code in other languages and modules.

If you will have `curl` code then you can convert it to python `requests` on https://curl.trillworks.com

Comment: it seems insomnia is basically a wrapper around https://github.com/Kong/httpsnippet